# Can I use Azure Service Relay with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

I want to use Azure Service Relay in my Python program. Is there any way to use it with Python?

Comment: How about this [Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python)?

Comment: Any updates now ?

Comment: Sorry, will work on it over the weekend. Also, I was thinking just to use Service Bus in case I caouldn't make it with Hybrid Connections. But let's see... I'll let you know guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know , `Azure Relay` does not have Python SDK. It only has [.Net SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-dotnet-api-overview). However , you could use it via [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/relay/) in your python program.